# Захват видео с веб-камеры пользователя

Tags: php, видео, потоки-данных

В общем стоит такая задача, необходимо сделать захват видео с веб-камеры пользователя, и записывать его на сервер, при этом во время записи, есть возможность прямого вещания...

Либо подскажите в какую сторону копать, либо платные скрипты я не знаю)

Заранее благодарю, и да, все это дело необходимо в итоге связать в веб-обвязку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложное решение, скажу я вам честно.

Раньше реализовывал с помощью видео-серверов. На опыте это - `Wowza Media Server`, но дорогая, сцука. И обязательно флеш на стороне клиента. Но, конечно, можно сделать и приопретарное ПО, как это сделали мне.

Еще как вариант: сейчас есть такая новинка, правда не во всех браузерах - возможность брать изображение с вебки javascript'ом. Суть заключается в том, что мы получаем картинку, каким-то образом кодируем её и отправляем туда, куда нам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо хоть какой-то толчек с мертвой точки, ну чтож почитаем про Wowza. А так вообще заказчики готовы оплатить любую сумму за все это... так что на стоймость Wowza я даже не смотрю)

Comment: Можете еще в сторону Cisco WebEx покопать.

Comment: @Quiss вот бы мне таких заказчиков) Мне пришлось вместо транскодера (который стоит столько же, сколько и сам видео-сервер) писать самостоятельно прогу.

Comment: Еще используют Cisco Video Surveillance Operations Manager.

Answer (score 2):

getUserMedia(js) + websockets. Из канваса берём base64 кадра и кидаем на сервак. Но это уж вообще извращение.

[Пример работы с getUserMedia](http://habrahabr.ru/company/intersystems/blog/145427/)

Comment: что только base64, в бинарном виде нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

haxevideo + crtmp + довести самому